# Blank Page Issue during creating an order from the Backend

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I've tried to disable all the third-party modules by deactivating without any luck. So, I checked from the console and I found the following:

[image: Blank Page Issue during creating an order from the Backend]

I just want a hint in where I should start.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look where vzero-integration-min.js is coming from. Looks like a third party integration.

Disable it and try again.

Comment: I have tried this and didn't make any difference.